# Question about plentyoffish.com asp.net functionality

Tags: asp.net

One the frontpage of plentyoffish.com, the 'Continue' button (for the form submission) links to register.aspx. From what I can see the system does not use postback. So, my question is, how is the form data posted to register.aspx? What would that code look like?

Comment: "Post" and "Post Back" are two different things, but they're related. That's a hint.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

i'm not sure if we're talking about the same thing here, but the continue seems to be an image type input, which works the same as a submit, and submits the form to register.aspx.

Answer (score 1):

If you look at the html source of the page, you will find the following code

```
<form method="POST" action="register.aspx" NAME="Register853049" onsubmit="return submitForms(this);">
```

The action is specified as register.aspx, so when this form is submitted to the server it is submitted to register.aspx